# Replace column names with placeholder in sqlite

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

Can I replace a column name with a placeholder in while querying data from a table in sqlite?

Example:

```
db.execute("SELECT ? FROM currency WHERE user_id = ?", ( "usd", 1).fetchall()
```

It returns the placeholder which is 'usd" or any string I replaced it with.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I replace a column name with a placeholder in while querying data from a table in sqlite

No.

Placeholders exist to separate data (i.e. values) from code (i.e. the structure and meaning of the SQL statement). This way placeholders prevent SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Column names are code in SQL. If it was possible to parameterize them, the data/code separation would break, making your SQL vulnerable to injection attacks again, defeating the whole point of placeholders.

Also, you should not want to. It indicates a design flaw in your database if that appears as something you need. If your column name is variable, it should probably be a column *itself*.

So this

```
SELECT ? FROM currency WHERE user_id = ?
```

should probably be

```
SELECT data FROM currency WHERE user_id = ? AND currency_symbol = ?
```